# Laravel Eloquent many to many how to add where?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `roles_title_index` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `role_user` (
  `role_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `role_user_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `role_user_role_id_foreign` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `role_user_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `role_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And I have two classes:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{

    /**
     * Roles of the user
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
}

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * Returns users for role
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Now how can i filter roles base on their title from class User method?
I think may be I need modify this somehow:

```
$this->roles()->getResults();
```

So, to assume I need a way to get specific role in User class

Comment: you have created a three table Roles,Roles_User,Users tables right?

Comment: @User that's the first thing stated in the question.

Comment: tel me one thing role_user is a pivot table?

Comment: Yes, I have three tables and two classes. role_user is a pivot table. I want to get specific role from class User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
class User extends Model {
    // find all users having the given title
    public static function withTitle($title) {
        return static::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($title) {
            $q->where('title', $title);
        })->get();
    }

    // determine if this particular user has the given title
    public function hasRoleByTitle($title) {
        $roles = $this->roles()->where('title', $title)->get();
        return 0 < count($roles);
    }
}
```

Example usages:

```
var_dump(User::withTitle('admin'));

$user = new User(242);
var_dump($user->hasRoleByTitle('admin'));
```

Untested, not near a L5 environment.  But should be in the ball-park!

Comment: @Iamzozo Thanks for confirmation on that!  Removed comment about any L4/L5 differences.

Comment: Actually I want to check if user have specific role

Comment: @user2975535 Ah, ok. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

In migration table you can try like this

**roles(migration):-**

```
 Schema::create('roles',function($table)
        {
            $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('title',150);
            $table->string('remember_token',100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**users(migration file):-**

```
   Schema::create('users',function($table)
        {
        $table->increments('users_id')->index();
        $table->integer('roles_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles'); 
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password',100);
        $table->string('remember_token',100);
        $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**role_user(migration file):-**

```
  Schema::create('role_user', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('roles_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles'); 
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); 
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

After run the migration files create a Model classes like this.

Model classes:

**roles.model:-**

```
class Roles extends Model  {

    protected $table = 'roles';

    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('users');
    }

}
```

**Users.model:-**

```
class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasMany('roles');
    }
}
```

If you need to use a different name for your pivot table, or override the associated keys, you can pass them in as optional arguments.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(
   'roles',          // related_table
   'user_conversations',     // pivot_table
   'users_id',                // key_1
   'roles_id'        // key_2
);
```

Comment: Didn't get how it will help to get specific role in class User

Comment: based on user id you can get specific role.